Why GORM automigrate will try to drop a non-exist index
I have a type as
type Customer struct {
    gorm.Model
    CorpId         string `gorm:"column:corpid"`
    Name string `gorm:"column:Name"`
    Age int
}

And I use GORM to do the auto migrate, like
dbErr = dbInstance.AutoMigrate(&models.Customer{})

This runs fine before.
I added a constraint to the CorpId, so now it becomes:
CorpId         string `gorm:"uniqueIndex;column:corpId"`

And suddenly the auto migrate doesn't work with following error:
ERROR: constraint "uni_customer_corpid" of relation "customer" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42704)

I checked the database, it created another index idx_customer_corpid but not uni_customer_corpid, and I wonder where this uni_customer_corpid come from.
I have tried to drop all the tables and then to a fresh automigrate and that works. But of course I can't drop table every time. So what can I do to avoid this issue?

This question is incomplete. You talk about CorpId, but show a field called Sid, which somehow you use interchangeably with this corpid field, but that doesn't make sense context. Show the full type(s) - there's possibly a relation between this table and another (incidentally, in case it matters, embedding gorm.Model will create an ID field, and there will be a PK constraint on the ID field from the Model type IIRC)

Sorry it's a mistake, should be just CorpId, basically I updated the model by adding a unique index, and then it seems GORM automatically add a UNI_CUSTOMER_CORPID constraint, but it doesn't exist in the DB actually and later during automigration it tries to delete this constraint though.

I had the same issue after updating my gorm version, and fixed it by updating the gorm mysql driver (from v1.5.1 to v1.5.7):
go get gorm.io/driver/mysql

I found the fix on this github issue https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/6966
